# WordPress "template_include" Filter Not Working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I created three plugins that define a custom post type and use `template_include` to include the template for the single post version.

For some reason, the latest one that I have built creates the records properly, but can't seem to find the template. The code is literally copied-and-pasted, so I'm not sure why this is the case. The only changes were to the names of the functions and post types to avoid conflicts.

Here is the part that adds the `template_include` filter:

```
function include_person_template_function($template_path)
{
    if (get_post_type() == 'featured_people') {
        if (is_single()) {
            if ($theme_file = locate_template('single-featured-person.php')) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'single-featured-person.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}

add_filter('template_include', 'include_person_template_function', 1);
```

Since the admin works fine, the only other part that could be the problem is where the post type is defined:

```
function create_featured_people()
{
    register_post_type('featured_people', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Featured People',
      'singular_name' => 'Featured Person',
      'add_new' => 'Add New',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New Featured Person',
      'edit' => 'Edit',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit Featured Person',
      'new_item' => 'New Featured Person',
      'view' => 'View',
      'view_item' => 'Featured Person',
      'search_items' => 'Search Featured People',
      'not_found' => 'No Featured People Found',
      'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Featured People Found in Trash',
      'parent' => 'Parent Featured Person'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'menu_position' => 15,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
    'has_archive' => true
  ));
}
```

A few other things to note:

- I have ruled out a caching issue.
- The other plugins use different function names and CPT names.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: a copy/paste of your code works for me. is `create_featured_people` hooked to `init`? note that there's also the `single_template` filter that fires for just singular post types, which will simplify your code a bit and not run on every other type of request.

Comment: @Milo That's really weird. I can't get the template to work in both local and remote WP installations, including a fresh install. Here's the complete code in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/justinkuepper/c550de53f24895e76dd44c11d8495fc3. Note: I updated the naming to see if it was a "people" to "person" issue.

Comment: that works for me as well, I can load a template from the theme dir as well as the plugin dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why this is, but I had to go to Settings > Permalinks and then click "Save" without changing anything. I think the file had to be rewritten to account for the new post type?

Regardless, it fixed the issue and I hope someone else can save a lot of time and headache by reading this!

Comment: Ah yes, I suppose I should have pointed out that rewrite rules need to be flushed after a new post type is added. Just visiting the Permalinks page will flush the rules, you technically don't have to click Save.